# Может ли gc удалить только что созданный объект до присвоения переменной?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Допустим у нас есть такая строчка:

```
Object object = new Object()
```

**Сценарий:**

1. Был создан объект `new Object()`, но ссылка него еще не была присвоена переменной `object`.
2. Был вызван `GC`. На наш объект нет
   ссылки и он его удаляет.
3. Переменная `object` остается без объекта.

Не думаю, что такое возможно, но не понимаю почему.

Comment: Возможно, если в течении времени объект не будет использован.

Comment: "на наш объект нет ссылки"... не понял, `Object object` - это не ссылка? или до вызова GC было выполнено `object = null` (либо object выпал из scope'a). "Был вызван GC" - это в логах JVM видно или просто выполнен вызов `System.gc()`? Если второе, то это не вызов GC, а только указание ему, что можно выполняться. Подробно про работу GC можно почитать, например [тут](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/garbage-collection/all-garbage-collection-algorithms/)

Comment: На месте разрабочиков java я бы озаботился тем, что бы GC не мог быть вызван в середине выполняемой операции вплоть до присвоения. что то мне подсказывает что они этим то же озаботились и вызывают GC только в безопасных точках.

Comment: подробнее про safepoints можно почитать [тут](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2015/12/safepoints.html)

Answer (score 7):

Потому что ссылка есть всегда. Ну сами подумайте, если сразу после окончания работы конструктора ее нет, то что мы потом присваиваем в переменную? 
Если вы посмотрите на байт-код создания объекта, то увидите что-то вроде

```
   0: new           #2 // class java/lang/String
   // память заказана, ссылка на неициализированный объект положена в стек операндов
   3: dup  // ссылка раздублирована
   4: invokespecial #3 // Method java/lang/String."<init>":()V
   // один экземпляр ссылки передан параметром в конструктор и там пропал
   7: astore_0  // второй экземпляр записали в локальную переменную
```

вот эти ссылки, лежащие в [стеке операндов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.2), так же учитываются сборщиком мусора, как и ссылки из переменных.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понял вопрос, речь идет о том, что:

> может ли мусорщик убрать объект между моментом его создания и присвоения к переменной

Ответ, нет не может. Идеология работы сборщика мусора в Java примерно такая (псевдокод):

```
void allocMemory(int n) { //просьба аллокации n байт из кучи
    if (heapTop - heapStart > n) //проверяем есть ли место в куче
      сollectGarbage();  //вызываем сборщик мусора
    heapStart += n; //обновляем указатель на начало свободной кучи
}
```

Соответственно сборка мусора будет происходить только перед созданием объекта, но не после него.

Понятно, что в реале все по другому, учитывая фрагментацию кучи и многопоточность, но в целом псевдокод приблизительно такой.

P.S. Вызов `System.gc()` - это не вызов сборщика мусора, а всего лишь просьба прибрать мусор

Comment: Многопоточность всё портит...

Answer (score 2):

Нет, такое невозможно. Ситуацию "переменная осталась без объекта" вы никогда не сможете увидеть, поскольку сборщик мусора спроектирован так, чтобы эту ситуацию вы никогда не увидели.

> *На самом деле, переменная "без объекта" остаться может - но только в том случае, когда вы никогда эту переменную не читаете (а значит, и не сможете увидеть собрал её сборщик мусора или нет)*